# How is it possible to link libraries like Selenium without using pip or conda install?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to perform headless testing. I performed those with Casperjs, but I am not allowed to code in it. I need to find a way to integrate selenium webdriver, but `pip install` or even `conda install` won't work. Is there a way out?

Comment: We're going to need to see your entered commands and the output before we can help. "It doesn't work" is an insufficient bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Download the source from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium
and install:

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install selenium library from  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium 
 on windows. The source files are in Tar format. Use 7zip tool or something to extract them and then go to the directory where it is extracted and then run above command python setup.py install.